# PHP incorrectly serializing a DateTime as `O:8:"DateTime":0:{}`

Tags: php, datetime, serialization

The title pretty much says it, but does anyone have any idea what could cause PHP (`PHP 5.6.13-0+deb8u1` on Debian Jessie) to sometimes serialize a `DateTime` object as `O:8:"DateTime":0:{}`? It's a fatal error to try to unserialize that string.

I'm seeing this happening while serializing a session.

The `DateTime` objects were originally created with `new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('UTC'))`

edit: this is happening randomly a small percentage of the time. The code involved works 99%+ of the time.

Comment: [Works for me](https://3v4l.org/l1Eru). Can you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example?

Comment: It's happening randomly (nb "sometimes") - which makes this much harder. I haven't been able to reproduce it in scripts.

Comment: Are you sure that you "sometime" don't switch to php < 5.3? It is the only thing I can think of

Comment: Yup, 5.3 isn't even installed on the system. Thanks for the idea just the same.

Comment: see the same issue on PHP 7.0.5. Can't create example it happens random